# Pandas pivot and subtotals

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

Using this data -

```
d2 = {'Division': ['DIV1', 'DIV2', 'DIV1', 'DIV3', 'DIV2'],'Region': ['DIV1-South', 'DIV2-North', 'DIV1-North', "DIV3-East", "DIV2-South"]
    ,'MD': ["Susie", 'Martha', "Jane", "Nichole", "Randall"], 'Month': ['JAN', 'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', "APR"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

Which looks like this:

```
    Division  Region        MD        Month
0    DIV1      DIV1-South    Susie    JAN
1    DIV2      DIV2-North    Martha    JAN
2    DIV1      DIV1-North    Jane    FEB
3    DIV3      DIV3-East        Nichole    MAR
4    DIV2      DIV2-South    Randall    APR
```

Thanks to the community here, I was able to pivot this data to get the totals for the various months:  Using this line of code

```
pivoted = df.pivot_table(index=['Division', 'Region', 'NP'], columns='Month', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

                        Month    APR    FEB    JAN    MAR
Division    Region        MD
DIV1        DIV1-North    Jane    0    1    0    0
            DIV1-South    Susie    0    0    1    0
DIV2        DIV2-North    Martha    0    0    1    0
            DIV2-South    Randall    1    0    0    0
DIV3        DIV3-East    Nichole    0    0    0    1
```

So, this may not be possible, but I have only found one reference online to producing a pivot result that includes subtotals for the various portions.  That example, unfortunately, did not work.

The ideal result is:

```
Month                                    APR    FEB    JAN    MAR
Division    Region                MD
DIV1        DIV1-North            Jane    0    1    0    0
            DIV1-North SubTotal         0    1    0    0
            DIV1-South            Susie    0    0    1    0
            DIV1-South SubTotal         0    0    1    0
            DIV1 TOTAL                  0   1   1   0
DIV2        DIV2-North            Martha    0    0    1    0
            DIV2-North SubTotal         0    0    1    0
            DIV2-South            Randall    1    0    0    0
            DIV2-South SubTotal         1    0    0    0
            DIV2 TOTAL                  1   0   1   0
DIV3        DIV3-East            Nichole    0    0    0    1
            DIV3-East SubTotal          0    0    0    1
            DIV3 TOTAL                  0   0   0   1
```

This is a bit of a mindbender and may not even be possible, but since this is fairly easy in Excel pivot tables, I was hopeful that somewhere pandas has enabled this functionality and I just cannot locate it.  (Which has been true to this point despite days of searching and testing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `Division` *Total* and `Region` *SubTotal* by grouping with the respective levels by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`GroupBy.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), as follows:

```
pivoted2 = pivoted.reset_index()

# Create `Division` Total
df_Div_sum = pivoted2.groupby('Division', as_index=False).sum()
df_Div_sum['Region'] = '_' + df_Div_sum['Division'] + ' Total'
df_Div_sum['MD'] = ''

# Create `Region` SubTotal
df_Reg_sum = pivoted2.groupby(['Division', 'Region'], as_index=False).sum()
df_Reg_sum['MD'] = '_' + df_Reg_sum['Region'] + ' SubTotal'

# Concat results and set index + sort index
df_out = (pd.concat([pivoted2,
                     df_Reg_sum,
                     df_Div_sum
                    ])
            .set_index(['Division', 'Region', 'MD'])
            .sort_index()
         )
```

**Input Setup**

```
d2 = {'Division': ['DIV1', 'DIV2', 'DIV1', 'DIV3', 'DIV2'],'Region': ['DIV1-South', 'DIV2-North', 'DIV1-North', "DIV3-East", "DIV2-South"]
    ,'MD': ["Susie", 'Martha', "Jane", "Nichole", "Randall"], 'Month': ['JAN', 'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', "APR"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d2)

pivoted = df.pivot_table(index=['Division', 'Region', 'MD'], columns='Month', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

**Output**

```
print(df_out)


                                    Month  APR  FEB  JAN  MAR
Division Region      MD                                      
DIV1     DIV1-North  Jane                    0    1    0    0
                     _DIV1-North SubTotal    0    1    0    0
         DIV1-South  Susie                   0    0    1    0
                     _DIV1-South SubTotal    0    0    1    0
         _DIV1 Total                         0    1    1    0
DIV2     DIV2-North  Martha                  0    0    1    0
                     _DIV2-North SubTotal    0    0    1    0
         DIV2-South  Randall                 1    0    0    0
                     _DIV2-South SubTotal    1    0    0    0
         _DIV2 Total                         1    0    1    0
DIV3     DIV3-East   Nichole                 0    0    0    1
                     _DIV3-East SubTotal     0    0    0    1
         _DIV3 Total                         0    0    0    1
```

### Extended Test Data

As your sample data only have one data per `Region`, I have added some more test data for more complete testing:

**Input Setup**

```
data = {'Division': ['DIV1', 'DIV1', 'DIV2', 'DIV2', 'DIV1', 'DIV1', 'DIV3', 'DIV3', 'DIV2', 'DIV2', 'DIV2'],
 'Region': ['DIV1-South', 'DIV1-South', 'DIV2-North', 'DIV2-North', 'DIV1-North', 'DIV1-North', 'DIV3-East', 'DIV3-East', 'DIV2-South', 'DIV2-South', 'DIV2-South'],
 'MD': ['Susie', 'Susie2', 'Martha', 'Martha2', 'Jane', 'Jane2', 'Nichole', 'Nichole2', 'Randall2', 'Randall3', 'Randall'],
 'Month': ['JAN', 'FEB', 'JAN',  'MAR', 'FEB', 'APR', 'MAR', 'APR', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pivoted = df.pivot_table(index=['Division', 'Region', 'MD'], columns='Month', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

print(pivoted)

Month                         APR  FEB  JAN  MAR
Division Region     MD                          
DIV1     DIV1-North Jane        0    1    0    0
                    Jane2       1    0    0    0
         DIV1-South Susie       0    0    1    0
                    Susie2      0    1    0    0
DIV2     DIV2-North Martha      0    0    1    0
                    Martha2     0    0    0    1
         DIV2-South Randall     1    0    0    0
                    Randall2    0    1    0    0
                    Randall3    0    0    0    1
DIV3     DIV3-East  Nichole     0    0    0    1
                    Nichole2    1    0    0    0
```

**Output**

```
print(df_out)

Month                                      APR  FEB  JAN  MAR
Division Region      MD                                      
DIV1     DIV1-North  Jane                    0    1    0    0
                     Jane2                   1    0    0    0
                     _DIV1-North SubTotal    1    1    0    0
         DIV1-South  Susie                   0    0    1    0
                     Susie2                  0    1    0    0
                     _DIV1-South SubTotal    0    1    1    0
         _DIV1 Total                         1    2    1    0
DIV2     DIV2-North  Martha                  0    0    1    0
                     Martha2                 0    0    0    1
                     _DIV2-North SubTotal    0    0    1    1
         DIV2-South  Randall                 1    0    0    0
                     Randall2                0    1    0    0
                     Randall3                0    0    0    1
                     _DIV2-South SubTotal    1    1    0    1
         _DIV2 Total                         1    1    1    2
DIV3     DIV3-East   Nichole                 0    0    0    1
                     Nichole2                1    0    0    0
                     _DIV3-East SubTotal     1    0    0    1
         _DIV3 Total                         1    0    0    1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                         "small", "large", "small", "small",
                         "large"],
                   "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})
```

**Output**

```
     A    B      C  D  E
0  foo  one  small  1  2
1  foo  one  large  2  4
2  foo  one  large  2  5
3  foo  two  small  3  5
4  foo  two  small  3  6
5  bar  one  large  4  6
6  bar  one  small  5  8
7  bar  two  small  6  9

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'],
                    columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

**output pivot table**

```
table
C        large  small
A   B
bar one    4.0    5.0
    two    7.0    6.0
foo one    4.0    1.0
    two    NaN    6.0
```

Comment: This looks like a standard pivot_table and does not seem to address the question about "subtotals"

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my actual data is above.  I added the code for the sample dataframe for ease of use.  But, your code is pivoting from a new set of data you provided while the data I am working from is a multi index df resulting from the first pivot of the original data.

Comment: @SeaBean Your response worked perfectly.  Thank you for taking the time to add that.  I upvoted your answer.  Definitely a complicated case and you nailed it!